# Activating node agent for Jenkins from mac terminal, not connecting getting that output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Any ideas what's causing it?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /remoting: Read-only file system
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:389)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:690)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:797)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:783)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager.initializeWorkDir(WorkDirManager.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:321)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:297)
```

Comment: [Some more context would help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but seems self-explanatory ... "Read-only file system"

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a custom working directory:
`java -jar agent.jar -workDir ~/Jenkins`